# Why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)$ and $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

This is a very elementary question.
In Matsumura's book "Commutative ring theory", I've found the following isomorphism:
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5).$$
As a quotient ring is involved, my idea is to use the first isomoprhism theorem, i.e. I want to define a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ whose kernel is exactly $(X^2+5)$, but here I get stuck.

Indeed,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_nX^n\mapsto a_0+a_1\sqrt{-5}$$
is a group homomorphism w.r.t. $+$, but this is not a ring homomorphism as
$$\Big(\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^i\Big)\Big(\sum_{i=0}^mb_iX^i\Big)=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}(\sum_{k=0}^i a_kb_{i-k})X^i\mapsto a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)\sqrt{-5}$$
which is different from
$$(a_0+a_1\sqrt{-5})(b_0+b_1\sqrt{-5})=(a_0b_0-5a_1b_1)+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)\sqrt{-5}.$$

What's the right idea to get this isomorphism **using** the first isomorphism theorem?

**PS:** Similarly, I've seen that $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$ and the various proofs define explicitly an isomorphism, but how can I obtain this result from the **first isomorphism theorem**?

Comment: Take the evaluation map $f: \Bbb Z[X] \longrightarrow \Bbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$ defined by $x \rightarrow \sqrt {-5}$ and which is identity on $\Bbb Z.$ Then the $f$ is an onto ring homomorphism with kernel $(x^2+5).$ Then use first isomorphism theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

$$\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb C\;,\;\;\phi p(x):=p(\sqrt{-5})$$

Observe that the image is $\;\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\;$ , and the kernel is...

For the second one, try

$$\psi:\Bbb R[x]\to\Bbb C\;,\;\;\psi p(x):=p(i)$$

Comment: I have some trouble when I try to compute the kernel... :/ assume I don't know that the kernel is $(X^2+5)$, is there a simple idea to get it?

Comment: I try to be more explicit: $0=\sum_{k=0}^n a_n(\sqrt{-5})^n=\sum_{k\,\text{even}}a_n(-5)^{\frac{n}{2}}+\sum_{k\,\text{odd}}a_n(-5)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\sqrt{5}$ and I'm not able to go on.

Comment: @LBJFS It is much simpler: observe that $\;q\in\ker\phi\iff q(\sqrt{-5})=0\iff (x+\sqrt{-5})\,\mid q(x)\;$ . But now take into account that $\;q\;$ is a real polynomial and thus its complex roots appear as conjugate pairs...